# OAUTH2 transaction manager grails mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, grails, oauth2client

I am working on an app that uses a mongodb, is built in grails, and is using oauth2 as an authentication service. I have the services and controller built out (I think) and am trying to run my server to manually test connectivity with google. I am running into an "Error creating bean with name transactionManagerPostProcessor..." that I can't solve. I know I need to either install a plug-in that takes care of the "transactions" for me, or create a bean in resources.groovy.

I have done a lot of researching and reading up on this, but I have been at a dead end for the last couple days trying to get this implemented. Can someone tell me how to solve this problem, create the correct bean, or install the correct plug-in? Partial stack trace below, with link to full stack trace:

```
|Loading Grails 2.3.4
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
............................................
|Running Grails application
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
Error |
2014-01-16 09:30:52,840 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  -             Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name     'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/format/datetime/DateFormatterRegistrar
```

Full stacktrace can be found at: http://pastebin.com/5mW5uwtu

I have tried adding

```
static transaction = 'mongo'
```

to the service that calls google to authenticate the user. This is a solution I found on a similiar question on stackoverflow. I have also fiddled with different plugins and dependencies in my build-config. Not sure what else there is to try.

Thank you!

Comment: That's a big stack! As a tip, consider pasting big stacks such as this in http://pastebin.com/ or similar and posting a link here.

Comment: Thanks, will do. As one can tell, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

To work around this issue with some plugins, I've added the following to the beans block in resources.groovy

```
// some plugins need a transaction manager, 
// although the mongo one isn't properly transactional
// and could produce unexpected results in some cases.
springConfig.addAlias('transactionManager', 'mongoTransactionManager')
```

However, the specific error you're seeing relates to the Spring class DateFormatterRegistrar not being found. Are you using an up-to-date version of Grails (e.g. 2.3+) and the mongo plugin? Have you added the mongo plugin as a compile plugin dependency in BuildConfig?:

```
compile ":mongodb:1.3.3"
```